# Using regex capturing groups to dynamically return the group that matches the criteria

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have URL string such as `/questions/12314454/syntax-error`. I use the following regex with capturing groups in a [nginx map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) to get a number and replace it with a static string i.e. ID.

```
"~(.*/)([0-9]{5,})(/.*)$" $1ID$3;
```

However, above only works when I know that the number would be appearing in the second path of URL or second capturing group and won't work for URL such as:

```
/questions/syntax-error/73914774/
/73914774/questions/syntax-error/ 
/73914774/questions/73914774/ 
etc.
```

My question is how if possible, I can use regex's capturing groups to automatically return the group which matches a given criteria such as a number in this case, so I can replace it accordingly?

Comment: What do you mean "it won't work"? How exactly "doesn't it work"? Do you only want to match when the digits are the 2nd part of the path?

Comment: @Bohemian queite the opposite currently i replace the 2nd part in all the cases. What i want is to actually know which part of the path (capturing group) does contain numbers, so i can replace only that

Comment: Which match do you expect here, as there are 2 numbers? `/73914774/questions/73914774/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to use 1 of the capturing groups, then drop the others and only keep the one you want. So in this case:

```
^.*[^0-9]([0-9]+).*$
```

Comment: Ramire sorry didnt get you but what i understand from your example that for e.g.`^.*[^0-9]([0-9]{5,}+).*$` will return the group or the numbers greatan than 5 in length irrespective of where they appear in the path?

Comment: This is what the regex captures using your examples https://regex101.com/r/0BGLW3/1

Comment: Ok but how do i retrieve the matched value? Doing `$1` returns nothing. Also this regex `^.*[^0-9]([0-9]+).*$` doesnt differentiae between different sections of url in between `/`.